# How to prevent the form of being closed when AcceptButton is pressed in C#

Tags: c#, forms, events, acceptbutton

I have a `Form` which has an “Ok” `Button` that is assigned as `AcceptButton`. When I click this `Button` or press `Enter` key the `Form` is automatically closed, as expected.
Under the event `OkButtonClick` I wrote a routine to check if all the fields were correctly filled, case not an error message is thrown through a `MessageBox`.  The problem is that after close the `MessageBox` the `Form` is automatically closed, but I would like it remains opened to allow user to correct his inputs. In this case, how should I do to prevent that `Form` was closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that click event, if your validation fails, add this line

```
 this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
```

The inner working is more or less the following:

The general rule is that the form engine automatically closes a form if its DialogResult property is set to anything but DialogResult.None.

When a form's engine receives a click on a button, the engine sets the forms DialogResult property to the value present on the button's DialogResult property, then calls the event handler. If you do nothing, at the exit of the event handler the engine looks at the forms DialogResult property and reacts accordingly. So you need to set the DialogResult back to None if you want to counteract the default behavior.